# How to set inputmask using the time format in PXTimeSpan

Tags: c#, erp, acumatica

I have a `StartTime` field, I want to fill the field with the time format `hh:mm:ss`, but when I apply it to a `PXFormView`, it only displays the hour and minute. How can I make it display `timespan` with `seconds` format? I'm overriding the DAC object with the following attributes:

```
protected int? _CapacityStart;
[PXDBInt()]
[PXDefault(0)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Start")]
```

code from aspx below,

```
<px:PXTimeSpan TimeMode="True" ID="edCapacityStart" runat="server" DataField="CapacityStart" InputMask="hh:mm:ss" AllowNull="False" Size="S" ></px:PXTimeSpan>
```

[image: screenshoot result]

Comment: I believe the timespan works by saving the time in minutes into the INT field. If minutes is the lowest stored value I don't see how you will be able to get seconds. You might need to look into using a date time field and displaying the time portion only.

Answer (score 0):

As Brendan states, the PXTimeSpan control won't let you add secconds. But you can use a DateTime field.

Here is code for a custom attribute that allows you to save the seconds instead of the minutes in the DB.

```cs
using System;
using PX.Data;

namespace PX.Data
{

    #region PXDBSecTimeSpanAttribute

    /// <summary>Maps a DAC field of <tt>int?</tt> type to the <tt>int</tt>
    /// database column. The field value represents a date as a number of
    /// seconds passed from 01/01/1900.</summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <para>The attribute is added to the value declaration of a DAC field.
    /// The field becomes bound to the database column with the same
    /// name.</para>
    /// <para>The field value stores a date as a number of seconds. In the UI,
    /// the string is typically represented by a control allowing a selection
    /// from the list of time values with half-hour interval.</para>
    /// </remarks>
    /// <example>
    /// <code>
    /// [PXDBSecTimeSpan]
    /// [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Run Time")]
    /// public virtual int? RunTime { get; set; ]
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    public class PXDBSecTimeSpanAttribute : PXDBTimeSpanAttribute
    {
        #region State

        /// <summary>
        /// The "00:00:00" constant.
        /// </summary>
        public new const string Zero = "00:00:00";

        /// <summary>
        /// The BQL constant representing string "00:00:00".
        /// </summary>
        public new sealed class zero : Constant<string> { public zero() : base(Zero) { } }

        #endregion State

        #region Ctor

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance with default parameters.
        /// </summary>
        public PXDBSecTimeSpanAttribute() : base()
        {
            _InputMask = "HH:mm:ss";
            _DisplayMask = "HH:mm:ss";
        }

        #endregion Ctor

        #region Implementation

        /// <exclude/>
        public override void FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_AttributeLevel == PXAttributeLevel.Item || e.IsAltered)
            {
                e.ReturnState = PXDateState.CreateInstance(e.ReturnState, _FieldName, _IsKey, null, _InputMask, _DisplayMask, _MinValue, _MaxValue);
            }

            if (e.ReturnValue != null && (e.ReturnValue is int || e.ReturnValue is int?))
            {
                TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, (int)e.ReturnValue);
                e.ReturnValue = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).Add(span);
            }
        }

        /// <exclude/>
        public override void FieldUpdating(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewValue == null || e.NewValue is int)
            {
            }
            else if (e.NewValue is string)
            {
                DateTime val;
                if (DateTime.TryParse((string)e.NewValue, sender.Graph.Culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out val))
                {
                    TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(val.Hour, val.Minute, val.Second);
                    e.NewValue = (int)span.TotalSeconds;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.NewValue = null;
                }
            }
            else if (e.NewValue is DateTime)
            {
                DateTime val = (DateTime)e.NewValue;
                TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(val.Hour, val.Minute, val.Second);
                e.NewValue = (int)span.TotalSeconds;
            }
        }

        #endregion Implementation

        /// <summary>Returns the date obtained by adding the specified number of
        /// seconds to 01/01/1900.</summary>
        /// <param name="seconds">The seconds to add to the default date.</param>
        public static DateTime FromSeconds(int seconds)
        {
            TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, seconds);
            return new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).Add(span);
        }
    }

    #endregion PXDBSecTimeSpanAttribute 
}
```

You can add it to the code secction of your Customization Project and then use it in a custom field or replace the attribute of an existing PXDBInt timespan field where you would like to also save seconds like this:

```cs
[PXDBSecTimeSpan]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Start")]
public virtual int? CapacityStart { get; set; }
```

And use a PXDateTimeEdit control with TimeMode enabled to edit the value:

```
<px:PXDateTimeEdit runat="server" ID="edUsrSpanStart" DataField="UsrSpanStart" TimeMode="True" />
```

[image: SecTimeSpanField]